# Difference between the very soon and in a jiffy

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> I will be with you **very soon**

vs.

> I will be with you **in a jiffy**

Which of the two sentences is more correct?

Comment: The biggest difference is that ***very soon*** is standard English, suitable for all contexts. But ***in a jiffy*** is a quirky colloquialism that's becoming increasingly dated.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence

> I will be with you very soon

is perfectly correct whether written or spoken.

The second version

> I will be with you in a jiffy

is rarely written, and is an idiom that may or may not be in fashion in any particular milieu.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally correct from a grammatical point of view.

According to Collins Dictionary

[**in a jiffy**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-a-jiffy)

> If you say that you will do something **in a jiffy**, you mean that you
>   will do it very quickly or **very soon**.

you will do something in a jiffy = you will do something very soon

The expression "in a jiffy" is not marked as old-fashioned or archaic but if we compare the ngrams offered by Google, it seems that "in a jiffy" [red] is less used today.

[image: n-gram]

Answer (score 0):

There can be an emotional difference.

When a person tells you that they will be with you **in a jiffy**, there is an expression of empathy that you are waiting and they acknowledge this and they will try to hurry or at the very least not dawdle.

When a person tells you that they will be with you **soon**, there can be an expression that you are expected to have the empathy and understand that they are busy, and you should try to be patient or at least not become impatient.